# actionPerformed not working

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

so I created a menu of three buttons, each one will open another window. I added the buttons to the actionListnener, I check the Source, I did everything. but still it's a dummy button.

enough talking, I think it's better if you guys see the code.
Thank you in advance!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MainMenu extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton decB;
    private JButton hexB;
    private JButton binB;
    private JLabel label1;

    public MainMenu()
    {
        setTitle("Hello Dear Friend");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 323, 303);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo( null );

        JButton decB = new JButton("Decimal");
        decB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        decB.setBounds(79, 85, 146, 42);
        decB.setBackground( new Color( 212, 208, 199 ) );
        decB.setFocusPainted( false );

        JButton hexB = new JButton("Hexadecimal");
        hexB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        hexB.setBounds(79, 138, 146, 42);
        hexB.setBackground( new Color( 212, 208, 199 ) );
        hexB.setFocusPainted( false );

        JButton binB = new JButton("Binary");
        binB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        binB.setBounds(79, 191, 146, 42);
        binB.setBackground( new Color( 212, 208, 199 ) );
        binB.setFocusPainted( false );

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Select the base you wish to convert: ");
        label1.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 12));
        label1.setBounds(20, 11, 277, 63);

        contentPane.add(decB);
        contentPane.add(binB);
        contentPane.add(hexB);
        contentPane.add(label1);

        ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
        decB.addActionListener( bh );
        hexB.addActionListener( bh );
        binB.addActionListener( bh );
    }
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        DecMenu dm = new DecMenu();
        BinaryMenu bm = new BinaryMenu();
        HexMenu hm = new HexMenu();

        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event)
        {
            setVisible( false );

            if( event.getSource() == decB )
                dm.setVisible(true);

            else if( event.getSource() == hexB)
                hm.setVisible( true );

            else if( event.getSource() == binB )
                bm.setVisible( true );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see? It does not look like you have done anything with the menus so when they are displayed, there is nothing to show. Have you put some print statements in the action listener code? I bet they are firing just fine.

Comment: I'm expecting the other frame to appear after clicking the button. and yes I have printed statements in the actionlistener, which means the actionlistener is working, but as I said I don't see any menus.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
event.getSource().equals(decB);
```

or  replace:

```
JButton decB = new JButton("Decimal");
```

with:

```
this.decB = new JButton("Decimal");
```

and so on for the other fields.

---

Edit:

The `==` operation on objects in Java checks to see if they are the same objects. Your local variables hides the field variables so that when you call

```
event.getSource() == decB
```

you are effectively calling

```
event.getSource() == null
```

You can check this by using `System.out.println(this.decB)` in your code

Comment: I don't see how that will help. they're both appropriate object instantiations.

Comment: +1, @altaha0a, you have both class and instance variables. The class variable (which is what you check in the ActionListner) is null. Follow the advice from above to get rid of the instance variable and then you will be initializing your class variable.

Comment: Yes. that did work! Thank you very much sir. you solved a great dilemma.

Comment: @altaha0a, don't forget to accept the answer so people know the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

These menu objects aren't added anywhere. A component can only be visible, if it is added to a container.

Edit:

As *@medPhys-pl* noted (+1), the global buttons are effectively distinct from the locals (in the constructor). This results that the `if` test will never pass true.

Either remove the "type prefix" in the constructor (recommended, `this` not required), or use equals (discouraged).

Comment: please forgive my lack of expertise, I'm relatively new at programing. I did add them and still there is nothing.